# How to Start SignalR service globally

Tags: xamarin.forms, signalr

am working on chat application with SignalR and I am facing one problem.
    SignalR service take few second for start and user wait for start service.
    after Disapper the chat page the service has closed.

How to always open SignalR Service.

I have call this code on Chat page constructor

```
  Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () => {
                if (!SignalRClient.IsConnectedOrConnecting)
                    SignalRClient.Start();

                return true;
            });
```